# BottlePy pre-request processing

Tags: python, uwsgi, bottle

I'm looking for a way to have all requests going inside a function `foo()` before going into the *routes*.

That way I'll be able to read the `request.environ` before doing the real work.

I'm trying to do this so that I don't repeat code, but cannot find a way to do such a thing in **BottlyPy**...

My setup is: nginx -> uwsgi -> bottlepy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's what [plugins](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/plugindev.html) are used for.

Here's an example:

```
import bottle
from bottle import request, response

def foo(callback):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        # before view function execution
        print(request.environ)  # do whatever you want

        body = callback(*args, **kwargs)  # this line basically means "call the view normally"

        # after view function execution
        response.headers['X-Foo'] = 'Bar'  # you don't need this, just an example

        return body  # another 'mandatory' line: return what the view returned (you can change it too)
    return wrapper

bottle.install(foo)
```

Comment: Do you mean I should write my own plugin just to initialize some stuff for wich I need to read request.environ?

Comment: Exactly. It's not difficult to make Bottle plugins.

Comment: Awesome, thanks you very much for your very simple code example.